# Browser "security shield" causing problems

Tags: civievent, joomla, registration

I have a user who attempted to use the Brave Browser to register for an event. However he was unable to get past filling out the registration information. Then he "lowered the security shield" and was able to get through to the confirmation page. This is Joomla and was civicrm 5.29 although I just updated to 5.30 since that happened.  Is this a known thing? Is there something I should to to warn people as part of the process?